# Google App Script: How do we load gmail draft without refreshing the page?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

For the context, I am trying to develop a google workspace app using GAS. This app allow user to open a gmail draft by clicking a button, make some edits and send out emails.

I can get the `draft message Id` in format: `lLtBPZxfP ...`

and we can open a draft using this link: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=<draft-message-id>`. However this would lead to a full refresh of the page which isn't a good user experience.

Is there another other way to load the gmail draft without full page refresh? I noticed that when you visit Draft folder in the gmail and clicks on any draft, it pops up without refreshing the page.

I have checked GAS documentation on gmail: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail

Didn't manage to find any meaningful resolution to this problem

Below is the code snippet I have used in GAS

```js
// Handling Add New Campaign
function handleAdd(e) {
    // Fetch the list of draft messages
    var drafts = getDraftMessages();

    // Fetch the list of draft messages
    var selectedDraftId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('selectedDraftId');

    // Check for no drafts
    if (!drafts.length) {
        return [CardService.newCardBuilder()
            .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
            .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("No drafts available.")))
            .build()];
    }

    // Create the draft selection dropdown
    var draftDropdown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
        .setTitle("Select a Email Draft")
        .setFieldName("selectedDraft");

    // Populate dropdown with drafts
    drafts.forEach(function(draft) {
        draftDropdown.addItem(draft.subject, draft.id, draft.id === selectedDraftId);
    });

    // View Draft button
    var viewDraftAction = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('handleViewDraft');
    var viewDraftButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('View Draft')
        .setOnClickAction(viewDraftAction);

    // Build the card
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
            .addWidget(draftDropdown)
            .addWidget(viewDraftButton))
        .build();

    return [card];
}

function getDraftMessages() {
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
    var draftMessages = drafts.map(function(draft) {
        return {
            id: draft.getMessage().getId(),
            subject: draft.getMessage().getSubject()
        };
    });
    return draftMessages;
}

function handleViewDraft(e) {
    var selectedDraftId = e.formInput.selectedDraft;
    var draftUrl = selectedDraftId 
        ? "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=" + selectedDraftId 
        : "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts";

    Logger.log("This is a log message ${draftUrl}");

    var openDraftLink = CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl(draftUrl)
        .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.FULL_SIZE);

    var openDraftButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText("Proceed to Draft")
        .setOpenLink(openDraftLink);

    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setName("Redirecting...")
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
            .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("Click the button below to proceed."))
            .addWidget(openDraftButton))
        .build();

    return [card];
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you are accessing the email draft using the app, is it pulling up the draft on the app's UI, or is it accessing through the Gmail UI? (which may be causing the refresh) Also, would you be able to provide a sample of the code that you are working on?

Comment: I am trying to somehow make the draft pulling up from the gmail interface like how you would have accessed the draft from your Draft folder but it seems that google app script does not allow interaction with gmail web elements. I have included the code I used so far, as you can see I can only make the user click on a link which brings to that specific draft, this would lead to a total refresh of the page

Comment: I'm intrigued that you already have a `draft message Id`. I _do_ note (and thank you) that you have identified a context for this question; but may I respectfully suggest that it might be more helpful to describe the _purpose_ of the app so that users can understand how/where the message content fits into the scheme of things. Personally, I am wondering whether it might be easier for a user to edit a "message file" that is later included as a parameter in sendmail.

Comment: The intention here is pretty straightforward which I have seen done before by other workspace app. The idea is that with the draft message Id, we can open up the gmail draft in a fashion that is similar to how a gmail user would experience when they clicks on an actual draft in their `Draft` inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Answering here so that others may chance upon as well.

In short, there is this function [setComposeAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setcomposeactionaction,-composedemailtype) which can be modified to open a draft.

While the example given in the documentation is for creating a new draft but the result effect would be the same if one were to load any `draft` object. So I modified my code to the following and it worked:

```
// driver code
var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('composeEmailCallback');
var viewDraftButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('View Draft')
        .setComposeAction(action,CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

// callback
function composeEmailCallback(e) {
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(drafts[0])  // I am using the first draft as example
        .build();
}
```